# Why i can't use $wpdb in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to make ajax in wordpress.

The php file is placed in plugins folder as a plugin

```
wp-content/ plugins/ my_plugin/ php-file.php
```

I know that Ajax receives informations from the php file because I did some tests, so the url in ajax is correct !

But when I want to pull some data from the database, I get this error in log file:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   get_results() on null in /home/......

I specify that I have an error 500 in the browser console (network tab)

my code :

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wplusersprofiles";
$user = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM my_table');
$live_Str = $user[0]->etat;
```

the problem is therefore is on line 3

Comment: Is the table you are accessing called wp_wplusersprofiles? Why are you using my_table in your query (you are not accessing $table_name table.

Comment: FYI, this is not the correct way to do this in a WP environment to begin with, you should not be making requests to your plugin’s script file location in the first place, but register appropriate actions. https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Thank you @misorude for the moment I do not know how to do it via ajax admin, can you direct me to a tutorial explaining the procedure from the beginning! because the tutorials that I consulted are vast and do not explain well where to put this code or to put that one! 
In fact I have no problem with php or javascript but my problem is in the paths.. where put the codes !

Answer (score 0):

Thank you jeff, Yes the 2nd line was not necessary, but according the log the probleme is in 3rd line ...

In fact This code return me data, i can see it in the top of the page , But this data can not be sent via ajax,  So i have always error that triggers instead of success :(

### This is my js code :

```js
$.ajax({
     url: "https://my-web-site.com/lab1/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/my-plugin.php",
     type: "POST",
     data: {etat:"verif"},
       success: function(data) {
       
       if (data=='on')
       {
             activate_livestream(); // this is a simple js function
       }
       else {
         console.log('off');
       }

     },
     error:function(){
       alert('ERROOOOR'); // i get always this alert :( !!
     }
   })// $.ajax end
```

---